# Jinja2 Align render Label and checkBox

Tags: bootstrap-4, jinja2

I have the following form :

[image]

I need to align the checkbox with his label, I'm rendering the field using jinja2 as the follow :

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
     <h2>{{ form.confirm_del.label }}
       {{ render_field(form.confirm_del, class="form-control br32", id="confirm_del") }}
     </h2>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap built-in class `d-inline` [(documentation)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/)